# How to return variable from inner function in outer function in rust

Tags: rust

I am using the `rust-macios` crate and I have this simple function.

```
fn request_contact_permission() -> bool {
    let store = CNContactStore::m_new();


    store.request_access_for_entity_type_completion_handler(
        CNEntityType::Contacts,
        |granted: bool, _error: NSError| {
            if granted {
                println!("Access granted");
            } else {
                println!("Access denied");
            }
        },
    );

}
```

How can I get the `request_contact_permission` to return the value of `granted`? `request_access_for_entity_type_completion_handler` triggers a dialog and returns a value when the user interacts with the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact type of `store.request_access_for_entity_type_completion_handler`, I can't say for certain. But assuming it takes either an `FnMut` or an `FnOnce`, you can have it capture an outer variable mutably, and then return that outer variable.

```
let mut granted_result: bool = false;
store.request_access_for_entity_type_completion_handler(
    CNEntityType::Contacts,
    |granted: bool, _error: NSError| {
        granted_result = granted; // Capturing a variable from the outer scope
        if granted {
            println!("Access granted");
        } else {
            println!("Access denied");
        }
    },
);
granted_result
```